# REACT NATIVE : How to fetch API data (JSON) and insert into Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hello everyone i got API data from  but can't solve how to solve this problem , maybe any tips for the freshman?

Here, I attached screenshot of what i did already:

[image]

Comment: String literal require `${var_name}`

Comment: i did even like this , but didnt work(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image API you list doesn't return a URL. It returns JSON, just like your initial API response. So, you'll have to perform `fetch` requests for the images and store them, then refer to the URLs you got in your list. That'll require a bit more state.

Here's a working example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState({})
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(Object.keys(json.message)))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) { return; }
    data.forEach((dataItem,index) => {
      if (index > 5) { return; }
      let url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dataItem}/images`
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (!json.message[0]) { return; }
          setImages(prevState => ({...prevState, [dataItem]: json.message[0]            }));
        })
    })
  },[data])

    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{item} </Text>
              {images[item] ?  <Image
               style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                source={{
               uri: images[item],
               }}
              />  : null }
              <Text>Image: {images[item]}</Text>
            </View>)}
          />
      )
      }
      </View>
   );
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/5FjQnP1Xf

Note that in this example, I only get the first 5 images to avoid making a ton of API calls.

It's also not a particularly robust solution -- in the real world, you'd definitely want to do more error handling than I'm doing here, cache the images, etc -- this is just a basic proof-of-concept.

Comment: yeah, i tried to make here all of the API calls, and it gave me an error of that it is lowing the APP and make sure to use Pure Components